# Populating data in worksheet from VAB data entry form

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

With almost 0 knowledge in VBA I have created a Data Form to enter daily voucher with:

1. `MS Date and Time Picker`
2. `TextBox1` for `Amount` (validated for numeric value only - working fine)
3. `OptionButton1` for `Cash`
4. `OptionButton2` for `Cheque`
5. `TextBox2` for the name of person `Paid To` (maybe I can change it into a ComboBox?)
6. `TextBox3` for `Paid For` (any value can be entered)
7. `ComboBox1` for `Sub Category` (list is in Worksheet2 (List) - working fine)
8. `TextBox4` for `Remarks` (any value can be entered)
9. `CommandButton1` to add the data into Worksheet3(database)
10. `CommandButton2` to show the 'database' worksheet
11. `CommandButton3` to close the form (working fine)

A `CommandButton` is also in Sheet1(Form) to open the form (working fine).

I want to enter the data into the form and populate this data to Worksheet3(database) as 
`Date` in (B3), `Paid To` (C4), `Paid For` (D4), `Sub Category` (E4), `Remarks` (G4), `Amount` (H4).

(F4) is free for a `VLOOKUP`.

I also want to have a data edit option in the form that may be with an auto-generate voucher number with recall option.

Can any one help me with the appropriate code to do this?

**Note**: I am creating with Office 2007 but also want to use it in XP Professional

Answer (score 1):

On the first part of your question, it depends whether you want to populate worksheet3 on the click of a button or dynamically as the data is entered into the form.  I'm assuming the former as most forms have OK buttons on them.  If this is the case then you can write a subroutine based on the button click, to give a simple example:

```
Private Sub Enter_Details_OK_Click()
  Sheets("worksheet3").Range("B3").Value = Calendar1.Value 
'Change Calendar1 to the value of your date/time object and change "worksheet3" to the actual name of your worksheet.
  Sheets("worksheet3").Range("C4").Value = TextBox2.Value
'...and so on...
```

You are basically transferring the values from each text box into various cells.  I'm not sure what you mean on the second part of your question, that needs further clarification.

Hope this makes sense!